# Show $\frac{2ct}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{c^2t^2+x^2}dx$ is finite for for $0\leq \alpha<1$

Tags: integration

How can I show that the following integral is finite for $ 0\leq \alpha<1$

$$\frac{2ct}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{c^2t^2+x^2}dx$$

$t> 0, c>0$.

My plan was to split the integral into one part going from $0$ to $1$ and another part going from $1$ to $\infty$ but I could not find suitable bounds/estimations from above

[image]

Comment: For $x\geq 1$, $x^\alpha\leq x$ could help since there is no problem around $x=0$

Comment: Not directly linked to the question, but the integral has a nice closed form: $I=\frac{2\pi c^\alpha t^\alpha}{\cos\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}}$. It supports the idea that the integral converges even at $\alpha\in(-1;1)$

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where does this integral come from? It looks like it comes from a physics problem involving Euclidean space-time.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I added the complete task above. It's from financial mathematics in continuous time. The integral arises when you want to determine $\mathbb E[|C_t|^\alpha]$, as the density of $C_t$ is given by $f_{C_t}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{at}{a^2t^2+x^2}$. (In my question I simply wrote $c$ instead of $a$). $a$ originally comes from the parameter of the gaussian process given in the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha}}{c^{2}t^{2}+x^{2}}=\frac{1}{c^{2}t^{2}x^{-\alpha}+x^{2-\alpha}}$$
For $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded, hence integrable. For $x\in[1,+\infty]$, $f(x)<\frac{1}{x^{2-\alpha}}$. Since $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2-\alpha}}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ exists, $\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ exists and is finite.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so difficult. Let
$$f(x)=\frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+k^2}$$
Where e.g $k=ct$. It is important to note that as long as $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $k$ is real that $f(x)\geq 0~~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+$.  For $x\in [1,\infty)$ notice that
$$f(x)\leq \frac{1}{x^{2-\alpha}}$$
And for $x\in[0,1]$ that
$$f(x)\leq \frac{1}{x^2+k^2}$$
Therefore,
$$0\leq \int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x\leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+k^2}\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2-\alpha}}\mathrm{d}x$$
And these are now easy integrals. Can you finish the rest?